# 2048 Board creation

Tags: python, matrix

I am creating the logic behind the game 2048 for a school assignment. I have the board created but I need to be able to replace it when a move is done. The move comes in as an integer (0=N, 1=W, 2=S, 3=E). Is this the best way to create the board?

```
[[0 for x in xrange(4)] for x in xrange(4)]
```

Comment: That creates a board of zeroes, which you could use for empty values. However, you'll have to then repopulate the board with the actual values after each move. It would be significantly cleaner to use that to create the initial board state, then modify the existing state by some movement. Look into `zip` to flip the lists along a diagonal and make vertical moves simply.

Comment: An alternative would be [[0,0,0,0] for _ in xrange(4)]. Note the underscore in place of x, which in your solution is shadowed but doubly unused.

Comment: Thanks guys, want any other part of the assignment to help?

Comment: @ChrisArena I need to have it board = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 2, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]